# Refreshing drop down input fields from mysql according to another form on the same page that adds new item to mysql using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am working on a site that uses a MySQL database and coding is made with PHP. I have an upload page with input fields. On this page there is a drop down input field list I put the options with a mysqli_query selection. I have another form on this same page where the user can add a new item to the MySQL database that should be added to the drop down input field as well.

My idea was to put the code that selects the items from MySQL into a function and call it after a new item is added, but I have problems with connection parameters inside the function as they seems to be undefined inside the function. Maybe should I put the connection to another function?

Another thing is that I would like to achieve the above written (to see the new option in the drop-down list) without refreshing the page. Do I need AJAX for achieving that? Now the page is automatically refreshing when pushing the submit button for adding a new item to the list.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Corresponding parts of my code on the page are:
(this is the current working version without the needed solution)

```
//making the list for the drop down input field
include "./shortscript/connect_to_mysqli.php";
$sql = mysqli_query($dblink, "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM items") or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$item_list = '<option value=""></option>';
if($count > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $item_list .= '<option value="'.$row['item_id'].'">'.$row['brand']
                   .' '.$row['model'].' '.$row['category'].'</option>';
    }
}
mysqli_close($dblink);

//test input function
function test_input($link, $data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $data);
  return $data;
}

//adding new item on the other form
    if(isset($_POST['submit_new item'])) {
        include "./shortscript/connect_to_mysqli.php";
        $brand = test_input($dblink, $_POST['brand']);
        $model = test_input($dblink, $_POST['model']);
        $category = test_input($dblink, $_POST['category']);
        if($sqlAddCamera = 
           mysqli_query($dblink, "INSERT INTO items (brand, model, "
                               . "category) VALUES"
                               . "('$brand', '$model', '$category')") 
                or die(mysql_error()));    
    }
```

And the connect_to_mysqli.php file looks like:

```
<?php
//msqli connection

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'xy';
$dblink = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) 
        or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_set_charset($dblink, 'utf8');
?>
```

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is a meaningless concept.

Comment: `"they seems to be undefined inside the function"` - What parameters in what function?  Where do you call that function and how do you supply the parameters?  Be specific, we can't debug this for you.  `"Do I need AJAX for achieving that?"` - If you want to fetch data from the server without refreshing the page, yes.

Comment: You can redirect this page to itself when this page insert a new item to db. *If you don't want to use AJAX.

Comment: Yes, you are right that DISTINCT * is unncessery, I deleted DISCTINCT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split the code into an AJAX function, so every time you click to open the dropdown or trigger an action (add an item, delete an item..), it calls to the ajax function corresponding to the action (load,add,delete..)

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect page to itself by calling func. `header()` like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_new item'])) {
        include "./shortscript/connect_to_mysqli.php";
        $brand = test_input($dblink, $_POST['brand']);
        $model = test_input($dblink, $_POST['model']);
        $category = test_input($dblink, $_POST['category']);
        if($sqlAddCamera = 
           mysqli_query($dblink, "INSERT INTO items (brand, model, "
                               . "category) VALUES"
                               . "('$brand', '$model', '$category')") 
                or die(mysql_error()));    
                header("location:./filename.php");
    }
```

- If you don't want to use AJAX.

Comment: I tried, but it won't be the perfect soultion! Thanks! I have to do it with ajax...